# getting the same email multiple times (email duplication)

Tags: email, mail-forwarding

im not sure if this is the right place to ask, but it is some type of server / mail error so...

**The Problem:**

some emails that are sent to an email distributor reach all members of this distributor multiple times (3-17x).

**Facts:**

("All mails" meaning all mails with this problem, not the duplicates)

- All mails got .pdf files attached
- All mails send from different mail programs (also some from android)
- The duplicates arrive at a constant interval (egg. every 1h)
- The duplicates stoped in all cases around the same time (around evening)
- All duplicates have the same timestamp
- All mails and duplicates have the same email header only in a few cases the email ID changes in the duplicated emails
- The problem only occurred sometimes, if the email is resent by the sender, it reaches the mailbox only once.

I cant recreate the problem, when i send an email (with a .pdf) with the same subject and the same text to the distributor, everything is normal.

I have no idea what happens here, there is a connection between the mails but i cant find it.
I googled and searched in Forums for a day now but cant find a similar case.

Anyone got an idea what is happening here? Tipps, ideas or suggestions would be great!

Thanks

Lukas

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more information, like what is the MTA being used, what are its config files, what shows up in the log.

Comment: I dont have access to logs (or even config files) at the moment. The mail server is running fine for years so i guess its something with a mail forwarding or bad mail client.
My hope is that this sounds familia to someone. A "it could be XY problem" would help.

Comment: Not much point in guessing before you can investigate the systems.. but one thing that you might find in logs would be the sending side refusing to wait for confirmation of message receipt and (not knowing it went through) retrying later.

Comment: Check the mail logs on the destination domain's mail server.